# Looping through a directory to find matching files

Tags: python, file, loops, iteration, generator

I have a module that iterates through a directory and finds matching files, then does a transformation and sends an email. The module takes in the following command arguments:

`startDate`, `endDate`, and `fundCodes` and the format it will search for, will end up being something like this:

`citco_unmapped_positions_PUPSEN_2018-07-01_2018-07-09.csv`

My issue at the moment, is that the `fundCodes` argument will be an array of funds:

`['PUPSEN', 'POSUF', 'AGE']`

Which causes an issue in the following method:

```
def positions_file_search(self, fundCodes):
    # Get a list of the files
    files = set(os.listdir(self.unmappedDir))
    # loop through all the files and search for matching file
    for check_fund in fundCodes:
        # set a file pattern
        file_match = 'citco_unmapped_positions_{fund}_{start}_{end}.csv'.format(fund=check_fund, start=self.startDate, end=self.endDate)
        # look in the unmappeddir and see if there's a file with that name
        if file_match in files:
            # if there's a match, load unmapped positions as etl
            filename = os.path.join(self.unmappedDir, file_match)
            return self.read_file(filename)
        else:
            Logger.error('No file found with those dates/funds')
```

The problem with the method above is that it returns as soon as it finds a matching file and doesn't go through the rest of the funds.

I'm currently calling it like this in my `__main__.py` page:

`unmapped_positions = alerter.positions_file_search(alerter.fundCodes)
    ... does something afterwards`

It's working but, I need to figure out a way to do the same processing for each fund.

NOTE: I can't do something like:

```
for fund in alerter.fund:
     alerter.positions_file_search(fund)
    etc...
```

Since the email formatting would be repeated for each fund. I need to somehow modify my method instead. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn your function into a *generator* by replacing

```
return self.read_file(filename)
```

with

```
yield self.read_file(filename)
```

This would allow you to write:

```
for unmapped_positions in alerter.positions_file_search(alerter.fundCodes):
   ...
```

For more information on generators, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: Holy shit, this is great. It's very close to what I need, although It still repeats the same mail formatting when doing the `for` loop. But I think I can get it from here!